# Should I extend an interface or keep it independent?

Tags: php, interfaces, inheritance

I'm trying to decide whether to extend a base interface with additional methods or create several independent interfaces. I have a `Task` interface that looks like this

```
interface Task
{
    public function name();
    public function run(array $args);
}
```

Now I want to add optional `description` and `dependencies` methods. Should I create a new `DetailedTask` interface like this?

```
interface DetailedTask extends Task
{
    public function description();
    public function dependencies();
}
```

This way I could choose to implement either the base `Task` interface for a basic task class, or the `DetailedTask` interface if I needed a description and dependencies. Alternately I could create separate interfaces for the extra methods like this.

```
interface Describable
{
    public function description();
}

interface TaskDependent
{
    public function dependencies();
}
```

According to the interface segregation principle, the second is better because it is more flexible. However, I don't ever anticipate using `Describable` and `TaskDependent` on anything besides a `Task` instance. The extra interfaces just seem to add extra complexity. Which technique should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, with your question details:

> Now I want to add optional description and dependencies methods.

If you want an optional method, then you should not go for interface, because as per interface rules, you MUST need to define methods in implementation class. See [PHP interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php).

So according to that rule, your first solution will not work because if you define class that implements **DetailedTask**, then that class must define both method **description** and **dependencies**.

The second way will give you freedom to choose whatever interface you want to implement.

Comment: I understand that if I implemented the `DetailedTask` interface I would be required to implement all 4 methods. However I could still choose to implement the base `Task` interface without the extra methods. That's what I meant by "optional". **Edit**: I may have misunderstood you. If you meant that I would not be able to add just `description` or just `dependencies`, then that is a good point.

Comment: Yes, by having both methods description and dependencies in single interface, you will always have to implement it even if your implementation class needs only one of them, while creating 2 separate interface will allow you to implement any of them as per your need. so you need to implement 3 at a time OR 4 if you want

Answer (score 1):

Always go for separate interfaces in this case. As the task part is mandatory and the second part is optional.

Interface always forces to override all the methods mentioned in it.

Now think if you don't want to use the optional part. Still you will have to override it. Even if it doesn't do anything.